# Does the Hodge star operator respect complex structure?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

The Hodge star operator $\ast$ acts on the differential forms of a differential manifold sending $\Omega^{k}$ to $\Omega^{N-k}$. If the manifold is complex, then for $p+q=k$, does $\ast$ map $\Omega^{p,q}$ into some $\Omega^{a,b}$, where $a+b=N-k$.

Comment: The last question is ambiguous, but I think the 2nd sentence is
also a question, so 
you should put a question mark after it. You can find
the answer in many places, e.g. Griffiths-Harris page 66.

Comment: So yes in the sense you mean.

Comment: The last question is just a rewording of the previous line. Since it is non-essential and apparently confusing I'll delete it.  

Comment: Thanks for the reference. In the edition I've laid my hands it's page 82, but no worries. So the answer to my question is that for a complex manifold of dimension $2N$, the Hodge star operator sends $\Omega^{p,q}$ to $\Omega^{N-p,N-q}$?

Comment: I forgot to say that for  the above work, you need to choose $*$ with 
respect to a Hermitean metric or equivalently a Riemannian metric
$g$ satisfying $g(JX,JY)= g(X,Y)$, where $J$ is the complex structure.

Comment: Since $∗$ is a real operator, to be more precise, you should say that after complexifying the space of forms, and extending $∗$ to be complex linear, then indeed $∗$ maps $\Omega^{p,q}$ to $\Omega^{N-q,N-p}$. Frequently, it is preferable to use $\bar *$, which is the composition of $∗$ with complex conjugation, to map $\Omega{p,q}$ to $\Omega{N−p,N−q}$. This way, we have $\alpha \wedge \bar * \beta = g(\alpha, \beta) vol$, where $g$ is the Hermitian metric.

Comment: Our comments seemed to have crossed. Yes, p 82 not 66, and yes. (Be warned
that some authors use a different convention, where $N-p,N-q$ get switched. It's a question of whether $*$ is linear or antilinear.)

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help. @Donu Please just copy and paste your comments into an answer so I can mark as the accepted answer. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Abtan requested, I'm converting my comments to an answer:

Suppose that $X$ is an $N$ (complex) dimensional complex manifold endowed with a Hermitean metric, or equivalently a Riemannian metric g satisfying $g(JX,JY)=g(X,Y)$, where $J$ is the complex structure.
Let $*$ denote the $\mathbb{C}$-antilinear extension of the Hodge star operator to complex
valued forms (some people -- including me -- prefer to write this as $\overline{*}$ as Spiro points out in the comments). Then as one finds on page 82 of Griffiths and Harris,
$$*\Omega^{pq}\subset \Omega^{N-q,N-p}$$
where I'm following the notation in the question and writing $\Omega^{pq}$ for the
space of $C^\infty$ forms of type $(p,q)$.

Comment: Isn't the point that the antilinear extension sends p,q to N-p,N-q in contrast to what is written in your answer?